# Is there any way load a custom LLVM pass on swift?

Tags: ios, swift, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm a iOS developer, and I want to write a LLVM Pass to calculate function execution time for each function.

My project is wrote both Objective-C and Swift.

I know I can load my pass on clang by `-Xclang -load -Xclang xx.dylib`
But i don't know how to apply my pass on Swift.

I have try to `-Xcc -Xclang -Xcc -load -Xcc -Xclang -Xcc xx.dylib` but seems the pass is not executed.

I don't know why this post got an un-vote...

Comment: You can use https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode .

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm not wanna measure build time, but the execution time for each function. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no clang pass to swift compile frontend, but we can use swift pass for swift language.